# Reading input in using pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am trying to read in input from the command line using a pthread. The pthread would call a reading function. Having some trouble with this and I have read the POSIX documentation. Appreciate the help!

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t client_thread; // client thread
    int rc;
    string msg;
    cout<<"Please enter a message to send to the server: "<<endl;
    pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, readerT, &msg);

    cout<<"Msg is: "<<msg<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void * readerT(string * temp)
{
    cout<<"GOT IN HERE:\n"<<endl;
    getline(cin,*temp);
}
```

Current Error Msg:

```
Client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Client.cpp:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(std::string*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’
Client.cpp:33: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
```

Comment: join the created thread, so that the main thread will not come to an end.

Comment: i added the pthread_join(client_thread, NULL); after the cout<<"Msg is... but I get a bunch of errors with regards to invalid conversions :(

Comment: 1) Check return value of thread creation, make sure you edit the question with proper error message so that, engineers can help you with ease.

Comment: If your compiler supports c++11 you might consider using std::thread, see this example http://www.nullptr.me/2011/09/16/multithreading-in-c11-part-1/#.UxQXGolet4o

Comment: @Masterminder I have made few changes in my answer it should work now... check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

void * readerT(void* );
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t client_thread; // client thread
    int rc;
    string msg;
    cout<<"Please enter a message to send to the server: "<<endl;
    pthread_create(&client_thread, NULL, readerT, &msg);
    pthread_join(client_thread,NULL);
    cout<<"Msg is: "<<msg<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void * readerT(void * temp)
{
    string *tmp = (string*)(temp);
    getline(cin,*tmp);
}
```

Hope that will work...(try to analyze what was wrong with your code :-) )

Comment: Although you are roughly pointing to a bug, it still is not related to question at all. Moreoever, an answer should explain what is wrong and how it can be fixed (if ever).

Comment: I guess you haven't saw the original question... error was obvious and yes I havn't worked with pthread so was not aware of the syntax..

Comment: I think you should visit this before saying that .....http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: @HadeS I have made your suggested changes, however I still get these errors: 
Client.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Client.cpp:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(std::string*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’
Client.cpp:33: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’  ... Do I have to do some kind of casting? That line 33 error refers to where the pthread_create is

Comment: @Masterminder sorry for small mistake... changes return type from `void` to `void *`.. try now..

Comment: @HadeS do you mean the return type of the readerT function? I still get the same error

Comment: Just edited and added complete vote...worked for me should work for you too..Also read about  `pthread_join()` function..

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error message:

```
Client.cpp:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(std::string*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’
```

The thread function has to be of type:

```
void * (*)(void *)
```

To change this

```
void * readerT(string * temp)
```

to be

```
void * readerT(void * temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be two problems in your code

- callback_function of thread is wrong

  `void *readerT(string *temp)`

  to

  `void *readerT(void *temp)`
- use join function in main thread

If you don't do it, the main thread will soon quit after creating the `read_in` thread, so use a join function to wait the thread to complete.